# How to execute something only once within if-loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, if-statement, web

EDIT (more specific):

I have the following situation. I am building an experimental synthesizer interface with JavaScript. I am using the [howler.js](http://goldfirestudios.com/blog/104/howler.js-Modern-Web-Audio-Javascript-Library) plugin to handle audio.
The idea is that a sound is played if a certain condition is met. I have a number stored variable whose value changes via the **heading of an iPhone compass**. 
**I use [compass.js](http://ai.github.io/compass.js/). It has a variable called heading.**

```
$(function(){

    Compass.watch(function (heading) {
      $('.degrees').text(Math.floor(heading) + '°');
      $('#rotate').css('-webkit-transform', 'rotate(' + (-heading) + 'deg)');

       if (heading >= 10 && heading <= 30) {
       sound.play("myFirstSound"); 
       } 
       else if (heading >= 31 && heading <= 60) {
       sound.play("mySecondSound");
       } else { etc etc...
       });
});
```

Even if heading is constant the .play command is executed not once but over and over again causing the audio engine to run out of memory. How can I execute the commands within the if loops only once? I can not access the value of heading outside the compass function. I always get **var heading does not exist** error.

Comment: I don't see a loop in your code... I have to imagine it?

Comment: add counter/trigger variable...

Comment: IF is not a loop, but condition if that's what you're trying to say.

Comment: Sorry. I´m not yet familiar with the exact meaning of loop. Excuse me for my dilettant expression. I thought it might be a loop because the commands within the if are executed over and over again. Doesn´t it qualify as a loop then?

Comment: Yes, it does qualify as a loop when that happens, but when only looking at your code, we cannot see the loop.

Comment: You seem to be programming something beyond what you should be doing if you don't know a loop... and I think your ifs are in a loop of a sort for it to be triggered more than once. Maybe inside a function that gets triggered a lot.

Comment: I think you need to look at Javascript timers: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp

Comment: Oh yes. My code is indeed inside a jQuery function that contains a cosntantly changing variable and communicates with a plug-in. So getting my if-logic out of the function might stop it from endless triggering of sound.play(); ? 

JaredT, yes this is beyond what I am able to do. Yet. But beyond what I should be doing? I´m trying to learn.

Comment: How could it run over and over again if your trigger is by the user interacting? Maybe the user is at fault :)) Show how the ifs are being triggered..

Answer (score 4):

Take a Boolean variable like

```
var checkOnce= false;
if (myVariable >= 10 && myVariable <= 30) {
checkOnce=true;
    sound.play("myFirstSound"); 
    } 
    else if (myVariable >= 31 && myVariable <= 60) {
checkOnce=true;
    sound.play("mySecondSound");
    } else { etc etc...
```

In loop check the value of checkOnce. Loop will run till checkOnce=false

Comment: the OP wants to have a continous loop and then play different sound when `myVariable` value changes... this is looping just once...

Answer (score 3):

Create a `boolean flag` and play the sound only when `false`.

```
var isPlayed = false;
var oldValue = myVariable;

if (myVariable >= 10 && myVariable <= 30 && !isPlayed) {
    sound.play("myFirstSound"); 
    isPlayed = false;
}
```

Then initialize variable when needed... For what you say i guess you will need a variable to compare the values inside the loop and set `isPlayed` flag to `false`:

```
if (myVariable != oldValue)
    isPlayed = false;
```

Comment: I would like to add that he would have to add a flag for every condition with your solution. Only if the OP wants to play other audio besides the flagged audio at a single loop. Question not that clear.

Comment: OP wanna play a sound each time variable changes value, but just once to avoid memory problems... just a flag is needed...

Comment: To clerify. The idea is that only one sound is played for each condition. howler.js is built to provide as many nodes as possible. This is why I can play several instances of the same sound.

Answer (score 3):

Just use a boolean variable.

```
var alreadyPlayed = false;

for(somecondition){
   if(alreadyPlayed) continue;

   sound.play("myFirstSound");
   alreadyPlayed = true;
}
```

You get the idea.

Answer (score 1):

The boolean value is a good idea. You could also make a use of the `onend` property of the `sound` object, so you will know when you can start playing the sound again. Like this:

```
var playing = false;
sound.onend = function () { playing = false;  };

while (condition) {
   if (!playing & ...)
       ...
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Saw your edit to the question, add a delay to the next trigger, the compass might be firing too rapidly. Not familiar with compass.js but as I can see it, it fires per degree, and that is a lot... if you tilt the phone 180degrees thats 180 triggers. 
Something like,

```
setTimeout(function() { your_func(); }, 50);
```

for a 50ms delay

You can also limit the triggers available from 360 to 36 or less by adding a counter of 10, 1 degree is for 1 count. So it triggers only after 10 degree movement.

```
$(function(){
var counter = 0;
Compass.watch(function (heading) {
   if(counter <=10){
     counter++;
    }
    else{ 
   counter = 0;
  $('.degrees').text(Math.floor(heading) + '°');
  $('#rotate').css('-webkit-transform', 'rotate(' + (-heading) + 'deg)');

   if (heading >= 10 && heading <= 30) {
   sound.play("myFirstSound"); 
   } 
   else if (heading >= 31 && heading <= 60) {
   sound.play("mySecondSound");
   } else { etc etc...
   }       
   });
});
```

Comment: I tried it. Lot of weird stuff is happening now. Every function of the compass is timed out by 10 steps. What if I pace my if-logic outside the compass function? Wound that work? This opens another question, namely how to read out the heading variable outside the compass function? Thank you very much for your attention.

Comment: What weird stuff? I don't think you will be achieving anything really placing it out. from your code, you seem to be playing a sound every 30 degrees. Try to make your counter 30. Sorry I don't know the behaviour of the compass.js nor the compass in the phone. Does it trigger ever degree change?

Comment: Where was the heading variable declared? To quickly test, add a     console.log(header); just after the compass watch function. Try reading on closures to understand the variable scope within nested functions.

Comment: Thank you JaredT. The heading variable seems to be part of the plugin. It is not declared within my code. I suppose it is declared inside the compass.js instead. The plug-in seems to be looking for changes constantly. That would explain the behaviour. I thought of another solution. Since I am sending the degree number to the HTML in order to display it, I might as well add an event listener watching the content of the HTML element. It wouldn´t be elegant but if it works I´m happy with it.

Comment: you will just be passing triggers around. Not unless you limit the trigger, it will fire rapidly. What weird stuff is happening? I don't see anything wrong with the code, maybe a few touch ups like if the direction changes, play sound immediately. Have you tried the counter and setting it to 360/(how many sound you have)?

Comment: Well the weird stuff is basically that the update of the compass is also delayed. I also tried dividing the heading number by the number of sounds. 
Although not directly. I used an intermaediate variable for that. And I instinctively feel that it is a stupid idea of mine. 

I did this vor every slice of the circle:
`var headingByTen`
`if (heading<= 0 && heading>=36) { headingByTen=1;}` 
 Then I built my sound activator like this:
`if (headingByTen==1) { sound.play("myFirmstSound"); }`
Same thing happens. Constant updates. Endless instances until the buffer can´t handle it.

Comment: Thought of a better way. Why not make the conditions specifically like this.... if(heading ==10) .... if(heading == 40)... if(heading ==70). so that sounds will trigger when a certain degree change is met. something like the counter but easier to understand and might remove that delay. Show me the code change you make.

Answer (score 0):

Add just a small layer of abstraction that will keep track of what's currently playing.

```
var nameOfSoundPlaying = null;

function play(soundName) {
   if (nameOfSoundPlaying == soundName) { 
      return; 
   } else {
     if (nameOfSoundPlaying != null) {
        // stop currently playing sound (if still playing)
        ...
     }  
     nameOfSoundPlaying = soundName;
     sound.play(soundName);
   }
}
```

Then it'll simplify your code :

```
$(function(){

    Compass.watch(function (heading) {
      $('.degrees').text(Math.floor(heading) + '°');
      $('#rotate').css('-webkit-transform', 'rotate(' + (-heading) + 'deg)');

       if (heading >= 10 && heading <= 30) {
           play("myFirstSound"); 
       } 
       else if (heading >= 31 && heading <= 60) {
           play("mySecondSound");
       } else { etc etc...
       });
});
```