# Conditional statement inside for(var key in object) Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I have a json data with specific key as below:

```
var object = {"85":{"id":"50","nosurat":"2020-PKL-001","user_created":"02211"},"69":{"id":"50","nosurat":"2020-PKL-002","user_created":"02212"},"104":{"id":"50","nosurat":"2020-PKL-003","user_created":"02213"}};
```

So, in order to iterate it, I use for method.
The problem is how to make filters inside the for method, but only execute it once?

```
for(var keys in object){
   if(object[keys].nosurat == "2020-PKL-001"){
      functionx();
   }
}
```

In the above code, the **functionx()** executed 3 times, because once it's true, it will loop through as many key as my object has. How to make **functionx()** only executed once in a while, only when the condition is met, assuming that there will be another key that met the condition.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to execute something only once within if-loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28813349/how-to-execute-something-only-once-within-if-loop)

Comment: Put a `break;` on it

Comment: @AlwaysHelping he said he only wanted the function to execute once, not stop the loop once the function is executed. Big difference.

Comment: `functionx` is only one time executed.

Comment: `for...in` is a statement, not a method.

Comment: I now endorse @cars10m's answer. A beginner's explanation of what .some() does can be found here: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_some.asp

Comment: the question is unclear, even if you want to loop over and by just adding a simple break it would work as well, as others have stated before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

or you could use [`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some):

```js
var obj = {"85":{"id":"50","nosurat":"2020-PKL-002","user_created":"02211"},"69":{"id":"50","nosurat":"2020-PKL-001","user_created":"02212"},"104":{"id":"50","nosurat":"2020-PKL-001","user_created":"02213"}};
function functionx(o){console.log(o)}
console.log('=== correct behaviour ========================');
Object.values(obj).some(o=>o.nosurat=="2020-PKL-001" && functionx(o) || true);

console.log('=== alternative correct version ==============');
Object.values(obj).some(o=>o.nosurat=="2020-PKL-001" && (functionx(o),true) );

console.log('===== WRONG behaviour (previous version ======');
Object.values(obj).some(o=>o.nosurat=="2020-PKL-001" && functionx(o));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important}
```

**Edit**:
Oooops, I just corrected a tiny detail: I forgot to mention that in my original solution `functionx(o)` needed to return some "truthy" value, otherwise multiple calls *would* still have happened in `some()`!

I changed the relevant part of the code now to `(functionx(o) || true)`. This will make sure that `some()` will *definitely* stop after the first `functionx()` call (regardless of whatever `functionx` might return).

One further remark on the `&&` within the function of the `.some()` loop: the evaluation of boolean expressions follows strict "lazy" rules in JavaScript (as in almost every other language): terms are evaluated from left to right only *as far as necessary* to get the result of the whole expression. So if the term before the `&&` evaluates as `false` the overall result of the expression is  determined and nothing after the `&&` could change it anymore. Therefore `functionx` will *not* be called in these situations and `false` will be returned to the calling `.some()` loop.

Comment: Given the edits to OP's question, this is the correct answer.

Comment: nice job! this is what I'm looking for, Sir! so the best way is not to use for in, but use some(); thank you guys, you are a lifesaver!

Comment: No. if you add true, then it will be executed once, not once in a while everytime the condition(s) are met. Your code earlier was perfect.

Comment: The `|| true` at the end *is* necessary, see my edited post again. I changed the data slightly, so the match happens on the second element. In the "wrong" version the second *and* the third elements will be shown, which is *not* what OP wanted.

Comment: I tried your old code it worked as I wanted. I haven't tried for your new ones. Also, one more question to ask: what is the _&&_ inside the _some()_? As far as I see it execute the first function (the arrow function)  and then, execute the next one. Is it true? Thank you for your response, appreciate it a lot!

Comment: The "arrow function" within `.some()` is called *every* time. It has a single expression in it: the one with the `&&`. Please also see my latest explanation-edit above:  `functionx` will *only* be called if the comparison before the `&&` evaluates as `true`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, Sir. Although it took awhile for me to understand, I appreciate all means of help. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

```
for(var keys in object){
   if(object[keys].nosurat == "2020-PKL-001"){
      functionx();
      break
   }
}
```

Comment: The comments make clear this is not the behavior OP wants.

Comment: well, when I write the answer, I didn't see the comments

Comment: sorry for the confusion, you're not wrong. It is I who asked the wrong question. I appreciate all who wanted to help. Thank you.